# azure data factory update

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-machine-learning-service, ml-studio

I created two web services (Traning and predictive to use API's in the data factory.

1. memory_train
2. memory_train [Predictive_Exp.]

In data factory, I created ML Batch execution followed by ML Update Resource1. I used following API's and i/ps for my Data factory blocks.

ML Batch execution:

1. I created a linked service that access API and key of my trained model
2. I created i/p and o/ps in a blob storage account.

After this is a run , `.ilearner` file is stored in my blob

ML Update resource 1:

1. I created patch endpoint in my memory_train [Predictive_Exp.] end point
2. I created second linked service that uses patch end point API and key in linked service, for update Resource end point, I used patch endpoint API again.
3. I tried to switch several API's for mr second linked service from default and patch, none of them could update my predictive model

I get the following error for this Data factory block, can you suggest me if I am doing any mistakes

> ```
> Activity ML Update Resource1 failed: UpdateResource has failed with error: {   "error": {
>     "code": "EditableResourcesNotAvailable",
>     "message": "The specified resources do not exist or are not editable. Valid resource names: memory_train [trained model]."   } }.
> ```

Diagnostic details:

> job ID 011f3f75-8065-4835-bef5-143e7ae22111. Endpoint https://management.azureml.net/workspaces/324b91422294411f9fa65d624cdd507c/webservices/88c2f89a72f14a539d529a319598f5aa/endpoints/patch.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still have the error but if it is the case I think you should set your ML Update Resource as the following:

Go to your ML Update Resource / Settings / Trained Model : memory_train [trained model]